# foreach() porque tengo este warning

Tags: php

**hola me pueden ayudar porque me sale este warning alguna solucion**

> **Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/control/action_guardia.php** on line **45**

en la linea 45 tengo esto algo fallo ?

```
$api_url = "http://".$servidor->servidor()."/control/api/test_api_guardia.php?action=insert";  //change this url as per your folder path for api folder
    $client = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $form_data);
    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($client);
    curl_close($client);
    $result = json_decode($response, true);
    foreach($result as $keys => $values)
    {
        if($result[$keys]['success'] == '1')
        {
            echo 'insert';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hay algún caso en el que `$result` esté vacío o no pueda leerse como conjuntos clave-valor? Añade un `print_r` del contenido de `$result` **antes** de ejecutar el foreach

Comment: ok hare la prueba

Comment: json_decode puede devolver valores que no son array, generalmente NULL cuando hay un error, entonces inserta un `if($result) { }` y colocas el ciclo dentro.

Comment: Gracias amigo si pude resolver con el `if($result){}` me falto eso gracias :)